# Checking if the coin is biased. Flipping it 10000 times.

Tags: statistics

We flip a coin 10000 times. We got 5400 heads. Is the coin unbiased ?

**Edit:** I came to understand(hopefully) that what should I do is calculate $P(X \ge 5400)$ But what I get is $1 - P(Y < 8)$. How should I interpret this?

Comment: maybe...it's all probabilistic, you know...

Comment: @lvi: Hint: compute the condence interval for the fraction of heads that should turn up if we have an unbiased coin.

Comment: U mean we want to have approximately 5000 heads. But we have 400 more which is $\frac{400}{10000} = 4 \% $ It doesnt tell me much...

Comment: No, that calculation should show $5000 ~\pm~ 100$ for a $95$ % CI, but this result is well outside that. Based on this, what is the conclusion?

Comment: So what if I calculate $P(4900 \le X \le 5100)$ and then calculate $P(X \le 5400)$ - or $>$(?) - and show that the result is much different from $P(4900 \le X \le 5100)$ and $EX$ ?

Comment: The probability it is not biased is very small...

Comment: @user10676 No but I found out that 5400 is 8 times bigger than the standard deviation (which equals 50). So from what I understand the probability of 540 heads is $\approx 0$

Comment: @Lost1 I tried to reduce(sorry for my english) X to standard Score like this: $P(X \ge 5400) = P(\frac{X - 5000}{50} \ge \frac{5400-5000}{50} = P(Y \ge 8)$

Answer (score 0):

You can find the probability that, given the coin is unbiased, you get this result. However, the only thing you can say for sure that the probability that you get heads is $\in (0,1)$.

The result strongly suggests that the coin is biased though, since the probability that the result is $400$ or more off the mean $5000$, is about $10^{-15}$.

Comment: why $10^{-15}$ ? I can't figure that out.

Comment: Calculate the average and standard deviation for an unbiased coin. Calculate how many standard deviations your actual results are away from the average. Then there are formulas and tables that tell you how likely or unlikely it is to be that far away from the average. Can you do the first two calculations?